# how do i use autosar program on tiva EK-TM4c123GXL (ARM cortex M4)?

Tags: texas-instruments, autosar

i used matlab to generate autosar folder for a simulink model and i am wishing to integrate this folder with tiva and generate .elf file to be used on tiva i don't know if autosar drivers is supported on tiva EK-TM4c123GXL or not.

Answer (score 0):

First you need is to make sure that MCAL is developed with respect to the controller you going to use. 
If not then you need to port existing MCAL with respect to the controller you which to use..Its required to port all MCAL module, just port only the modules you are using in the application.

Based on existing MCAL it can contain 3 parts. 
 a. Parameter Definition File (PDF)
 b. Some sort of tool to generate configuration file from description file ( which is generated using PDF using some configuration tools like **vector Davinci**, **TATA Elxsi easyconfig** .. )
c. Now actual C source code.

one these are developed / ported you need to configure your MCAL module based on requirement.

As per AUTOSAR upper layers should be Hardware independent. So in ideal case you not suppose to face any issue.

BR
Jerry james.